# How do I add my python scripts to Anaconda library?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a python script `foo.py` that I wrote. In which directory can I put that script so that I can use `from foo import ***` without getting any error. I am using Windows system with anaconda.

Comment: linux or windows?. Or mac?

Comment: Edited@ArpitSolanki

Comment: If you think you need to move your script somewhere, then you are doing something wrong. What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Basically, the error is something like there is no such module or library.

Comment: agreeing with @cricket_007 I would suggest use the script directly in your project or just create a py package

Comment: if you are using foo.py in same directory then it should be imported w'out any error and if it is in different directory then you have to put a __init__.py

Answer (score 3):

In case of conda environments on windows you can simply check where the external packages for conda (or that conda environment) are installed.

For example type something like this into the Python prompt of your conda environment:

```
>>> import numpy   # or any other external package that you installed with conda
>>> numpy.__file__
'C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\work\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'
```

That gives you the path where you're normal packages would be installed (well, minus the `\\numpy\\__init__.py` part). So if I put a file in that directory, in my case `C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\work\\lib\\site-packages\\` then I can load it.

Just make sure that you really import a package that has been installed with `conda install` in that environment!

For example:

## C:\Anaconda\envs\work\lib\site-packages\fun.py

```
def c():
    return 10
```

## Python prompt (again)

```
>>> from fun import c
>>> c()
10
```

That will make the file accessible for the corresponding `conda` environment (and just there).